# When the result will reach the people?

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

Assume the result of an exam has been published.

After 5 minutes, First person knows the result.

In next 5 minutes, new 8 persons know the result, and in total 9 know it.

Again after 5 minutes, new 27 people know, and total 36 know.

In similar fashion, total 100, 225..... people keep knowing it on 5 minute interval.

**Challenge**

Given a total number of people knowing (n), and a starting time in hour and minutes, output when total n people will know the result.

Example: If start is 1:02, and n is 225 the output time will be 1:27.

In output colons of time aren't needed, you may input or output as list or seperate variables.

`n` will be always in the sequence of totals, i.e. (1,9,36,100,225....)

Comment: [Relevant OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A000537)

Comment: Do times wrap around? Can the hour be zero? Test cases would be good.

Comment: @xnor jour can be zero and time will wrap

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 85 bytes

```python
lambda h,m,x:[(h+(y:=(((((x**.5)*8)+1)**.5)-1)*2.5)//60)%24+(m+y%60)//60,(m+y%60)%60]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSFDJ1enwipaI0Nbo9LKVgMEKrS09Ew1tSw0tQ01wUxdIG0EpPX1zQw0VY1MtDVytStVgWyQgA6MA8Sx/wuKMvNKNNI0DHVMDHSMjEw1Nf8DAA)

The sequence of totals is just sum of first \$n\$ cubes.

It is a known formula that sum of first \$n\$ cubes is the square of \$n\$<sup>th</sup> triangular number ([Proof](https://mathschallenge.net/library/number/sum_of_cubes)), i.e.

\$
\{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\}^2
\$

If we assume given input is \$x\$, then

\$
\{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\}^2=x
\\
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\sqrt{x}
\\
n(n+1)=2\sqrt{x}
\\
n^2+n=2\sqrt{x}
\\
n^2+n-2\sqrt{x}=0
\$

We get a quadratic equation with \$a=1, b=1, c=-2\sqrt{x}\$

The formula for the quadratic equation is

\$
\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\$

We will only take the positive root and plug in

\$
\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\\
=\frac{-1+\sqrt{(-1)^2-4\times(-2\sqrt{x})\times1}}{2\times1}
\\
=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8\sqrt{x}}}{2}
\\
=\frac{(\sqrt{1+8\sqrt{x}})-1}{2}
\$

Which is the formula for the \$n\$, then we just multiply it by 5, divmod by \$60\$ and add with start time.

Comment: [Fails](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSFDJ1enwipaI0Nbo9LKVgMEKrS09Ew1tSw0tQ01wUxdIG0EpPX1zQw0VY1MdDRytStVQWwzg9j/BUWZeSUaaRqGOiYGOkZGppqa/wE "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") for input `1, 40, 225` among others.

Comment: @Dingus works now

Comment: The question is unclear on whether a 12 or 24 hour clock is in use, though comments suggest 24. In that case, this still fails when the time wraps back around, e.g. `23, 40, 225`.

Comment: You absolutely do not need that many sets of brackets

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 103 bytes

```
\d+
$*
(^1|11\1)+
$#1$*
(^1|1\1)+¶(.+)
$2$1$1$1$1$1
+`:1{60}
1:
+`1{24}:
:
(1*):(1*)
$.1:$.2
:(.)$
:0$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYg9CoNAGET7uUa@YteFxfn8KeYsEiKYIk0KSWe8lgfwYqsWMvB4b@b37/MdSxmmBKsQnvyTA@NZD97H1fsWcoowN95DeolLX6@gTufi7SoIgVXUBVimLDsUcjSoNpbi3sEbtX4A) Takes `n` on the first line and the time (including colon) on the second.Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
(^1|11\1)+
$#1$*
```

Take the square root.

```
(^1|1\1)+¶(.+)
$2$1$1$1$1$1
```

Add 5 times the triangular index to the minutes.

```
+`:1{60}
1:
```

Convert 60 minutes to an hour.

```
+`1{24}:
:
```

Ignore days.

```
(1*):(1*)
$.1:$.2
:(.)$
:0$1
```

Convert to decimal.